# Only Affect Certain Applications with Theme

Tags: themes

I like to use dark themes but they tend to cause problems with applications adapting their background to the system theme but not their font colors because they then print black characters onto a black background.

I only really care about Nautilus, Evolution, and Gnome Calculator having a dark background. Rhythmbox having a dark background would be nice, too (but not as important). Everything else should just use the standard theme "Ambiance". How do I do this?

Thank you guys in advance. :)

System: Ubuntu 14.04.4 64 bit.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried these and they didn't work. I didn't see anything change. (My current theme is a dark theme and I'd expect them to use a light theme when launching them via such a command. Is this correct? Does this work without additional software installed? Like is there a theme called "elementary" which I have to install in advance?)